# Server is freezing while trying to get a backup of MongoDB in docker composer

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, flask, amazon-ec2

I have a back-end API server created with Python & Flask. I used **MongoDB** as my database. I build and run **docker-composer** every time while I update my source code. Because of this, I always take a backup of my database before stopping and restarting **docker container**.

From the beginning I am using this command to get a backup in my default folder:

```
sudo docker-compose exec -T db mongodump --archive --gzip --db SuperAdminDB> backup.gz
```

This line worked well previously. Then I restore the database again after restarting the the **docker-composer** to enable my back-end with updated code. I used this command to restore the database.

```
sudo docker-compose exec -T db mongorestore --archive --gzip < backup.gz
```

But from today, while I am trying to take a **backup** from server while the docker is still running (as usual), the server **freezes** like the image below.

[image]

I am using **Amazon EC2** server and **Ubuntu 20.04** version

Answer (score 0):

First, stop redirecting output of the command. If you don't know whether it is working you should be looking at all available information which includes the output.

Then verify you can connect to your deployment using mongo shell and run commands.

If that succeeds look at server log and verify there is a record of connection from mongodump.

If that works try dumping other collections.

Answer (score 0):

After digging 3 days for right reason I have found that the main reason is the **apache**.
I have recently installed **apache** to host my **frontend** also. While apache is running the server won't allow me to dump **mongodb backup**. Somehow apache was conflicting with docker.

My solution:

**1. Stop apache service**

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

**2. Then take MongoDB backup**

```
sudo docker-compose exec -T db mongodump --archive --gzip --db SuperAdminDB> backup.gz
```